# Representation of precipitation data

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, saga, excel

I have an excel sheet of precipitation data of each month of some districts. I have also the shapefiles of these districts. How can I represent this data in these shapefiles.

Answer (score 1):

well, if the excel and the shapes have a field in common you can join the excel to your shp. If not you can make a common field between them and do the join.

Answer (score 0):

In ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop this is a two step process:

1. Use [Excel To Table (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000055000000) to convert your Excel file to a table (dBase or file geodatabase)
2. Use [Join Field (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000) to join the contents of your table to your shapefile based on a common attribute field.